# Mysql upper limit for count(*)

Tags: mysql, optimization, count, limit

I've got a query:

```
select count(*) from `table` where `something`>123
```

If the table has few million records, the query runs really slow even though there's an index on column `something`. However, in fact I'm interested in value of:

```
min(100000, count(*))
```

So is there any way to prevent MySQL from counting rows when it already found 100k? I've found something like:

```
select count(*) from (select 1 from `table` where `something`>123 limit 100000) as `asd`
```

It's much faster than `count(*)` if the table has a few million matching entries, but `count(*)` runs much faster when there are less than 100000 matches.

Is there any way to do it faster?

Comment: I'll assume it's a typo that one limit is `123` and the other is `23`.

Comment: What kind of column is `something`? Are you using InnoDB?

Comment: It's MyISAM table. We can asume the column is an int, but it has absolutely nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Just an idea, so I won't give it as an answer, but what about `count(id)` where `id` is the name of a distinct indexed column? I know this can sometimes be faster (and sometimes not) with other DBs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the points to comment, so I am posting this as an answer...

1. Have you tried using [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) to see if your index on `something` is actually being used? It sounds like this query is doing a [Table Scan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/how-to-avoid-table-scan.html). Ideally, you will want to see something like "[Extra](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html#explain-extra-information): Using where; Using index".
2. Out of curiosity, is `something` a nullable field?

As an aside, perhaps the query optimizer would do better with the following:

```
select count(*) as cnt
from table
where something > 123
having count(*) > 100000
```

Answer (score 0):

Might help to make better use of value range limitation.

```
select count(*) - (select count(*) from t where something <= 123) as cnt
from t
```

The other thing might be to have an update trigger counting.